# How will the lateral displacement produced by a glass slab change with increase in the angle of incidence

Tags: optics

**How will the lateral displacement produced by a glass slab change with increase in the angle of incidence...**

*Now we know that..*

now the lateral displacement will obviously increase but what will be the relation in between increase in angle of incidence and lateral displacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your slab has a certain thickness, say $d$. From Snell's law about refraction, calling $θ_i$ the angle between the incoming ray and the normal to the surface, $n_i$ the refractive index of the medium outside the slab, $n_m$ the refractive index inside the slab and $θ_m$ the angle between the ray in the slab and the normal to the surface:
$$ n_m \sin θ_m = n_i \sin θ_i $$
you can derive the angle $θ_m$:
$$ \sin θ_m = \frac{n_i}{n_m} \sin θ_i$$
Then, from basic trigonometry, you know that:
$$ \sin^2 θ_m + \cos^2 θ_m =1 \ \Rightarrow \ \cos θ_m = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 θ_m} $$
and, with $d$ as defined and $l$ length of the path of the ray inside the slab, you can write:
$$d=l\cdot\cos θ_m \ \Rightarrow \ l= \frac{d}{ \cos θ_m} $$
Calling $x$ the lateral displacement you are asking for:
$$ x = l \cdot \sin θ_m$$
By substituting in this equation, you can get your result as an expression of the angle of incidence, the refractive indexes and the thickness of the slab.